# How to load cache in QWebEngine?

Tags: c++, qt, caching

I'm porting a program from QWebKit to QWebEngine, and it had an offline mode. Users were able to download some files. And if these files are downloaded, they can be viewed and accessed from offline mode. But QWebEngine just shows "No internet connection" page. Is there any way to fix this, since I'be heard that QWebEngine uses Chromium and there's no dirrect way to manipulate cache

Answer (score 1):

The `QtWebEngineCore` module doesn't expose it - and for a good reason. There's no way to guarantee that it'd work, because merely opening a page in the browser doesn't guarantee that everything needed to show it *next time* will load. There's also no guarantee that the items in the cache have necessary time-to-live and won't be stale and flushed the next time you attempt to use the cache.

You must cache the pages yourself, and the pages must have been designed to be cacheable like that, and point the browser to a `file:///` URL of your cache. If you think of caching random web content that way: forget it, it's not going to work. It didn't work in WebKit either, it just pretended to, but things would be subtly broken.

Comment: The page is designed to be cachable. I just don't understand how to do it

Comment: To cache it, you wouldn't use the web engine, but manually request all the files using `QNetworkAccessManager`, dump them to a folder, then access them from that folder.

Comment: Yup. I think it works now. And how can I access it, so it would show something on the page, instead of "No internet connection"?

Comment: Use a proper file URL. It'll work and doesn't need internet connection. The pages of course need to use relative URLs only.

Comment: And what about QWebEngineProfile? Can I do something like QWebEngineProfile* prof= QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile();
prof->setCachePath("Folder path"); ?

Comment: You can do that, but without an internet connection, the cache won't be used, and you have no guarantee at all that the cache holds everything needed to display the page. An `http` scheme in a URL requires an internet connection. You're really trying too hard to do what's wrong. If it's true that the page is meant to be accessed offline, then it'll be easy to explicitly cache it and access it through the `file` URL scheme. Otherwise you're fooling yourself.